visual studio 2022 JavaScript project debug chrome getting error launch.json, unavailable esproj failed
In Microsoft visual studio 2022 I have created blank JavaScript project. I want to debug and put breakpoint in app.js and play Launch Chrome button. It popup and error "There were deployment erros.continue?" below is my build commands
Build started at 3:36 PM...
1>------ Build started: Project: NodeConsoleApp2, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>------ Deploy started: Project: NodeConsoleApp2, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>Starting deployment of project 'C:\Users\Asus\source\repos\NodeConsoleApp2\NodeConsoleApp2\NodeConsoleApp2.esproj'...
2>Launching the following configuration from launch.json:
2>
2>Deployment of project 'C:\Users\Asus\source\repos\NodeConsoleApp2\NodeConsoleApp2\NodeConsoleApp2.esproj' failed. Port unavailable: -1
2>An exception happened at deploy, the port -1 configured on launch.json is unavailable.
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 3:36 PM and took 01.674 seconds ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy completed at 3:36 PM and took 01.674 seconds ==========

Here is my launch.json file below
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "chrome://extensions/",
      "port": 9222,
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "--load-extension=${workspaceFolder}/output/build",
        "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

If i continue then i get another error
Failed to load extension from:
C:\Uuser\Asus\source\repos\NodeConsoleApp2\NodeConsoleApp2\output\build. Manifest file is missing or unreadable
So I would like to debug JavaScript application in chrome, how can a able to achieve this, is it really possible? I am using windows 11, should i need any modification in launch.json. should i need any configuration in visual studio below i have provided some information images. thanks


I have created blank javascript project in microsoft visual studio 2022. Then I have changed below code in launch.json file want to debug in chrome browser but i am getting error, So i want build the project and debug in chrome browser.
 "name": "Launch Chrome",
 "type": "chrome",
 "request": "launch",
 "url": "chrome://extensions/",
 "port": 9222,
 "runtimeArgs": [
   "--load-extension=${workspaceFolder}/output/build",
   "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
 ]

